# Update a Google Map on input change with Vue.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, vue.js

I am trying to update a Google Map automatically after a user enters values in 3 input fields: state, city, address.

I think I have most of the code to make this work but I am using a custom Vue directive that inserts the initial map. This is necessary because there is a `v-if` on the form that conditionally displays these inputs.

My code is as follows:

```
<fieldset v-if="activeStep === 1">
  <strong><%= f.label :city %></strong><br>
  <%= f.text_field :city, class: 'form-control', 'v-model': 'city', 'v-bind:readonly': '!byAddress', 'v-on:change': 'updateLocation' %>

  <strong><%= f.label :state %></strong><br>
  <%= f.text_field :state, class: 'form-control', 'v-model': 'state', 'v-bind:readonly': '!byAddress', 'v-on:change': 'updateLocation' %>

  <strong><%= f.label :address %></strong><br>
  <%= f.text_field :address, class: 'form-control', 'v-model': 'address', 'v-bind:readonly': '!byAddress', 'v-on:change': 'updateLocation' %>

  <strong>Map</strong><br>
    <div id="map-container" v-map="setDefaultLocation()">
    <div id='location-map'></div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

the style:

```
#location-map {
  height: 250px;
}

#map-container {
  padding: 15px 0;
}
```

the Vue:

```
Vue.directive('map', {
  // When the bound element is inserted into the DOM:
  inserted: function (el, binding) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('location-map'), {
      zoom: 15,
      draggable: false,
      panControl: false,
      scrollwheel: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      fullscreenControl: false,
      center: binding.value,
      disableDoubleClickZoom: true
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: binding.value
    });
  }
})

const progress = new Vue({
  el: '#listing-multistep',
  data: {
    activeStep: 0,
    city: '',
    state: '',
    address: '',
    lat: undefined,
    lng: undefined
  },
  methods: {
    setDefaultLocation: function() {
      return {lat: 37.7749, lng: 122.4194}
    },
    updateLocation: function() {
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder({types: ["geocode"]});
      geocoder.geocode({'address': this.address + ', ' + this.city + ', ' + this.state }, function(response, status) {
        if (status == 'OK'){
          marker.setVisible(true);
          map.setCenter(response[0].geometry.location);
          marker.setPosition(response[0].geometry.location);
          this.lat = response[0].geometry.location.lat();
          this.lng = response[0].geometry.location.lng();
        } else {
          marker.setVisible(false)
          this.lat = null;
          this.lng = null;
        }
      });
    }
  }
})
```

The problem is that the `map` and the `marker` variables are defined within the context of the `Vue.directive` but are not accessible from the Vue methods.

I think the code should work if I can somehow modify the `map` and `marker` objects stored in `Vue.directive`.

Can anyone think of a way in which I might make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can define map and marker data properties in Vue instance.

So data in Vue should be:

```
data: {
  activeStep: 0,
  city: '',
  state: '',
  address: '',
  lat: undefined,
  lng: undefined,
  marker: '',
  map: ''
}
```

Then you could access the Vue instance through vnode.context and assign the data properties.

Directive:

```
Vue.directive('map', {
  // When the bound element is inserted into the DOM:
  inserted: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('location-map'), {
      zoom: 15,
      draggable: false,
      panControl: false,
      scrollwheel: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      fullscreenControl: false,
      center: binding.value,
      disableDoubleClickZoom: true
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: binding.value
    });
    vnode.context.$data.marker = marker
    vnode.context.$data.map = map
  }
})
```

Demo: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/3qvtdgyd/)

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. I see the message `ReferenceError: marker is not defined` in the console.

Comment: That version fails to even compile :(

Comment: Added extra spaces. :)

Comment: The version that compiles ends up returning the message `TypeError: marker is undefined.` I've also tried adding `this.` but get a similar message: `TypeError: this.marker is undefined.` so it seems that from within the methods context I cannot access data within the directive context...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154350/discussion-between-danig2k-and-shubham-patel).